# Date Conversion from M20161 to Jan16

Tags: oracle, date

How to convert `M20161` to `Jan-16` in Oracle where `2016` is the year and `1` is the month.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 5):

If `"M"` literal is going to be always present, then just enclose it in double quotes in the format mask. Since there is no day part it'll default to first day of the month.

```
select to_date('M20161', '"M"YYYYMM') as res
  from dual
```

Result:

```
RES      
---------
01-JAN-16
```

To display the date in desired `Jan-16` format, use `TO_CHAR()` function and `Mon-YY` format model.

```
select to_char(to_date('M20161', '"M"YYYYMM'), 'Mon-YY') as res
  from dual
```

Result:

```
RES   
------
Jan-16
```